# Comma before "is that"

Tags: punctuation

:)

I came across a sample essay, and there was a comma before "is that" in it.
I am not sure why a comma is needed in that context. Can anyone help me with this?

Here is a short excerpt from the sample essay.

'The main reason as to why I agree with some parents’ attitude in regard to TV restriction, is that children do not have the willpower to self-regulate yet'.

Thank you.

Comment: The author of the sentence has written himself into a corner and has attempted an escape via punctuation.  To no avail.

Answer (score 1):

That comma is not correct.  The sentence is one very long clause.  It should be broken up -- either into two clauses, or two sentences.

Some parents say one should restrict TV watching.  I agree, mostly because children don't have the willpower to self-regulate.

Children don't have the willpower to regulate themselves, so I agree with parents who restrict their TV.

...Really it's an inefficient, poorly thought out phrase in what I would take to be a poorly thought out argument.  If you want to make an argument for restricting children's TV watching, I'm with you -- but don't do it like that.  How about this:

Parents need to rein in children's TV watching.  It's not good for them, and it's like an addiction: they can't necessarily control themselves.

Comment: The answer could use some references or at least explanation. Currently, the question has 4k views!